# Why google map API requires key to work with google map?

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

This is a link I have added to same project in test application as well as production server:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

But it works on test server but do not working on production server.
I am doing an auto geocoding by passing address and gets location from it.
The test server only gives warning saying `Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys...` but returns result.
But Production server says: `This service requires an API key` and no result getting returned.

If that mandatory then why it is working on test server.

In what case an `API` key is mandatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As announced in [this blog](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html) Keys are now (as of June 22, 2016) mandatory (the sensor parameter is no longer required):

> 1. We no longer support keyless access (any request that doesn't include an API key). Future product updates are only available for requests made with an API key. API keys allow us to contact developers when required and help us identify misbehaving implementations.

Can't say why it is working on the test server, unless the test server has been actively using the Google Maps API since before June 22, 2016, in which case it could be grandfathered for keyless access.

Comment: So how long it will last without `API` key. Do I need to provide `API` key for both servers or just for production as test server has access without key?

Comment: Keys are now mandatory.  If one of your servers is working without a key, great, that is a bonus. You would have to ask Google about the time frame, at this point they seem to be trying to leave legacy maps that don't have keys functional, so I would expect the keyless access to continue to be grandfathered until they have a reason to change it.